# Is there something like an SVN user profile?

Tags: linux, unix, svn

Is there something like a `~/.svnrc` or `~/.svn/*` where I can put svn command line options that will be applied to all svn commands I issue on the shell, e.g `--no-auth-cache`?!

The SVN version is 1.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first time the svn command-line
>   client is executed, it creates a
>   per-user configuration area. On
>   Unix-like systems, this area appears
>   as a directory named .subversion in
>   the user's home directory.

([Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html) in the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) online manual.)

There should be a file named `config` under ~/.subversion that's already heavily commented to get you started. As for your example, the [Config](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) section in the online manual has these:

> `store-passwords`
>
> This instructs Subversion to cache, or
>   not to cache, passwords that are
>   supplied by the user in response to
>   server authentication challenges. The
>   default value is yes. Set this to no
>   to disable this on-disk password
>   caching. You can override this option
>   for a single instance of the svn
>   command using the --no-auth-cache
>   command-line parameter (for those
>   subcommands that support it). For more
>   information, see the section called
>   “Client Credentials Caching”.
>
> `store-auth-creds`
>
> This setting is the same as
>   store-passwords, except that it
>   enables or disables on-disk caching of
>   all authentication information:
>   usernames, passwords, server
>   certificates, and any other types of
>   cacheable credentials.